# Microservices: What is the ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC line mean in docker.compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am looking at the code in eShopOnContainer under the docker-compose.override.yml. I can see a line in

> volumes:
>         - ./src/ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/apigw:${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC:-/app/configuration}

```
webshoppingapigw:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - IdentityUrl=http://identity.api              #Local: You need to open your local dev-machine firewall at range 5100-5110.
    ports:
      - "5202:80"   
    volumes:
      - ./src/ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/apigw:${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC:-/app/configuration}
```

What does the line in the volumes ${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC .. is? I would think it will create a volumes of something but the ${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC … I can't see where it define in the project even not inside the .env file.

When I went inside the docker-compose.override.prod, the line ${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME not even there.

Currently I have exception running the sample code, therefore I tried to do follow the code from eShopOnContainer but code a simple version so I can easily to follow. I start doing the ApiGateway and building up from there.

I don't know is this question eligible to be asked. People here very fuzzy of the question.

Comment: P.S. I am not an architect or even a senior level of developer, I am just a early level. I can't run the eShopOnContainer and have even posted exception on the browser but haven't got any response which lead to previous question downvoted for asking to have a simpler version of tutorial to try out from. That question have been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
volumes: - ./src/ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/apigw:${ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC:-/app/configuration}
```

That means:

Mount the `./src/ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/apigw` to the path mentioned by `$ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC`

If `$ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC` is *empty* (not defined), then use as a mount path `/app/configuration`.

That gives the opportunity to a user to override the default path by a path of his/her choosing.

```
docker run -e ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC=/my/path ...
```

Comment: Oh that make sense thank you... I used the docker command before didn't realize

Answer (score 0):

ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC which is an environment variable. The variable value may be exported/set in some place of the code or in the instance. ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC will be replaced with value, that's why you where not able to see ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC in docker instead the value in ESHOP_OCELOT_VOLUME_SPEC.